# How can I make my bones move more attractively?

Tags: mesh, rigging, weight-painting

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hello. I am a beginner attempting to model and rig a character. As you can see, rather than looking smooth my bones have a kind of jiggered look when it bends. I was told that weight painting would help this but I'm either doing it wrong or it isn't helping.

I understand that my mesh is pretty messed up bad could this have contributed to the jagged joints? The Vertex groups should be assigned correctly though.
I'd much appreciate some advice or a point in the right direction.

Looking forward to what you have to say.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: The more polygons you have on your joints the better and smoother your joint will look.

Comment: select the elbow edge loops and ctrl B to add 2 more edge loops / make sure that the Armature modifier of the object is above the Subsurf modifier / enable Preserve Volume option in the Armature modifier / in the Object Data menu of your armature switch the Display from Octahedre to B-Bones and in Edit mode shrink the bones with ctrl alt S / select your forearm bone and, in the Bone menu > Bendy Bones, add several segments / repaint the object in Weight Paint mode... it should improve

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand most of what you said. Pretty much everything after add 2 more edge loops.